# How to make a GridLayout fit screen size

Tags: android, widget

The `GridLayout` API docs is very difficult to learn ...... 
is there any one who can teach me how to set child `View`s to have something like "weight" of `LinearLayout` ?

Right now it looks like all are placed on the left hand side, 
I have tried many times and still can not make it like each one the half width of the screen.

Edited :  I don't know what can I do for when the childen are all `wrap_content` ......
    even if I want to set some image in specific size , this class helps me to make `ImageView` `wrap_content` .........it cannot operate normal , did I miss some setting ?!?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

**Note**: The information below the horizontal line is no longer accurate with the introduction of Android 'Lollipop' 5, as `GridLayout` *does* accommodate the principle of weights since API level 21.

Quoted from the [Javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html):

> **Excess Space Distribution**
>
> As of API 21, GridLayout's distribution of excess space accomodates
>   the principle of weight. In the event that no weights are specified,
>   the previous conventions are respected and columns and rows are taken
>   as flexible if their views specify some form of alignment within their
>   groups. The flexibility of a view is therefore influenced by its
>   alignment which is, in turn, typically defined by setting the gravity
>   property of the child's layout parameters. If either a weight or
>   alignment were defined along a given axis then the component is taken
>   as flexible in that direction. If no weight or alignment was set, the
>   component is instead assumed to be inflexible.
>
> Multiple components in the same row or column group are considered to
>   act in parallel. Such a group is flexible only if all of the
>   components within it are flexible. Row and column groups that sit
>   either side of a common boundary are instead considered to act in
>   series. The composite group made of these two elements is flexible if
>   one of its elements is flexible.
>
> To make a column stretch, make sure all of the components inside it
>   define a weight or a gravity. To prevent a column from stretching,
>   ensure that one of the components in the column does not define a
>   weight or a gravity.
>
> When the principle of flexibility does not provide complete
>   disambiguation, GridLayout's algorithms favour rows and columns that
>   are closer to its right and bottom edges. To be more precise,
>   GridLayout treats each of its layout parameters as a constraint in the
>   a set of variables that define the grid-lines along a given axis.
>   During layout, GridLayout solves the constraints so as to return the
>   unique solution to those constraints for which all variables are
>   less-than-or-equal-to the corresponding value in any other valid
>   solution.

It's also worth noting that [`android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayout.html) contains the same information. Unfortunately it doesn't mention which version of the support library it was introduced with, but the [commit that adds the functionality](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/commit/b1dbd65b4e8ce2c889381214d0bc44aff8dfe616) can be tracked back to July 2014. In November 2014, [improvements in weight calculation and a bug was fixed](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/commit/5f355e700d63f67b1641f023d95e18c69c596ecb).

To be safe, make sure to import the latest version of the gridlayout-v7 library.

---

The principle of 'weights', as you're describing it, does not exist with `GridLayout`. This limitation is clearly mentioned in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html); excerpt below. That being said, there are some possibilities to use 'gravity' for excess space distribution. I suggest you have  read through the linked documentation.

> **Limitations**
>
> GridLayout does not provide support for the principle of *weight*, as
>   defined in weight. In general, it is not therefore possible to
>   configure a GridLayout to distribute excess space in non-trivial
>   proportions between multiple rows or columns. Some common use-cases
>   may nevertheless be accommodated as follows. To place equal amounts of
>   space around a component in a cell group; use CENTER alignment (or
>   gravity). For complete control over excess space distribution in a row
>   or column; use a LinearLayout subview to hold the components in the
>   associated cell group. When using either of these techniques, bear in
>   mind that cell groups may be defined to overlap.

For an example and some practical pointers, take a look at [last year's blog post introducing the `GridLayout` widget](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.nz/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html).

---

**Edit:** I don't think there's an xml-based approach to scaling the tiles like in the Google Play app to 'squares' or 'rectangles' twice the length of those squares. However, it is certainly possible if you build your layout programmatically. All you really need to know in order two accomplish that is the device's screen dimensions.

Below a (very!) quick 'n dirty approximation of the tiled layout in the Google Play app.

```
Point size = new Point();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
int screenWidth = size.x;
int screenHeight = size.y;
int halfScreenWidth = (int)(screenWidth *0.5);
int quarterScreenWidth = (int)(halfScreenWidth * 0.5);

Spec row1 = GridLayout.spec(0, 2);
Spec row2 = GridLayout.spec(2);
Spec row3 = GridLayout.spec(3);
Spec row4 = GridLayout.spec(4, 2);

Spec col0 = GridLayout.spec(0);
Spec col1 = GridLayout.spec(1); 
Spec colspan2 = GridLayout.spec(0, 2);

GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(this);
gridLayout.setColumnCount(2);
gridLayout.setRowCount(15);

TextView twoByTwo1 = new TextView(this);
GridLayout.LayoutParams first = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row1, colspan2);
first.width = screenWidth;
first.height = quarterScreenWidth * 2;
twoByTwo1.setLayoutParams(first);
twoByTwo1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
twoByTwo1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
twoByTwo1.setText("TOP");
twoByTwo1.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
gridLayout.addView(twoByTwo1, first);

TextView twoByOne1 = new TextView(this);
GridLayout.LayoutParams second = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row2, col0);
second.width = halfScreenWidth;
second.height = quarterScreenWidth;
twoByOne1.setLayoutParams(second);
twoByOne1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
twoByOne1.setText("Staff Choices");
twoByOne1.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
gridLayout.addView(twoByOne1, second);

TextView twoByOne2 = new TextView(this);
GridLayout.LayoutParams third = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row2, col1);
third.width = halfScreenWidth;
third.height = quarterScreenWidth;
twoByOne2.setLayoutParams(third);
twoByOne2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
twoByOne2.setText("Games");
twoByOne2.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
gridLayout.addView(twoByOne2, third);

TextView twoByOne3 = new TextView(this);
GridLayout.LayoutParams fourth = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row3, col0);
fourth.width = halfScreenWidth;
fourth.height = quarterScreenWidth;
twoByOne3.setLayoutParams(fourth);
twoByOne3.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
twoByOne3.setText("Editor's Choices");
twoByOne3.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large_Inverse);
gridLayout.addView(twoByOne3, fourth);

TextView twoByOne4 = new TextView(this);
GridLayout.LayoutParams fifth = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row3, col1);
fifth.width = halfScreenWidth;
fifth.height = quarterScreenWidth;
twoByOne4.setLayoutParams(fifth);
twoByOne4.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
twoByOne4.setText("Something Else");
twoByOne4.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
gridLayout.addView(twoByOne4, fifth);

TextView twoByTwo2 = new TextView(this);
GridLayout.LayoutParams sixth = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row4, colspan2);
sixth.width = screenWidth;
sixth.height = quarterScreenWidth * 2;
twoByTwo2.setLayoutParams(sixth);
twoByTwo2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
twoByTwo2.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
twoByTwo2.setText("BOTOM");
twoByTwo2.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large_Inverse);
gridLayout.addView(twoByTwo2, sixth);
```

The result will look somewhat like this (on my Galaxy Nexus):

[image: Tiled layout using GridLayout]

Comment: i have read it , but i want to ask is there some other things can do the same thing , i just want to made something similar the play store tiles layout .

Comment: @rex: I updated my answer with a very crude example. Hope that will at least give you some pointers for further development.

Comment: Thanks a lot,  I think a lot time ,still trap at the childen wrap content problem, now you save me! !

Comment: I believe it is possible to achieve this kind of layout using the rowSpan and columnSpan attributes...

Comment: @Justin: Feel free to mock up an example. We couldn't get it to work with a pure xml-based approach, so I'm sure there'd be interest in a 'proper' solution. I know I'd like to see it.

Comment: @MH I will see what I can do

Comment: Is it truly necessary to set the `LayoutParams` twice for a given widget? (First in `setLayoutParams`, then in `addView`)

Comment: @Didia: no, that's probably not necessary. It's more likely I just overlooked that when I came up with the sample code. As mentioned in the answer, it is a *"(very!) quick 'n dirty"* proof of concept; not suitable for production code or copy-and-paste. That was never the intention too. :)

Comment: i am new to grid view but i need to creat above grid view can you please share you whole example code.

Comment: @simmant: there's not much more to show. Just copy-paste the code into i.e. the `onCreate()` method of your activity and call `setContentView(gridLayout)` to set the `GridLayout` as content view. If that doesn't make sense, I suggest you have a read through the [Training section](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) on d.android.com.

Comment: @MH. can you please help me in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49944627/gridview-and-its-images-is-not-fit-for-all-screensize

Comment: @Nikson: `Gridlayout` and `GridView` are two completely unrelated viewgroups. Looks like you already have some good pointers in answers to your question.

Comment: This answer could have been abbreviated to "Use `layout_rowWeight` and `layout_columnWeight` in the items inside the `GridLayout`" but it's still good

Answer (score 13):

After many attempts I found what I was looking for in this layout.
Even spaced LinearLayouts with automatically fitted ImageViews, with maintained aspect ratio. Works with landscape and portrait with any screen and image resolution.

[image: Nexus 7]
[image: Nexus 5]
[image: Nexus 10]

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffcc5d00" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="10dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image1"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@drawable/stackoverflow"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="10dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image2"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@drawable/stackoverflow"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="10dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image3"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@drawable/stackoverflow"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="10dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image4"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@drawable/stackoverflow"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: can u pls tell me will it work if i want to make collage type layout ..... bacause i m setting images from gallery not from drawable or may i need to adjust size dynamically ?

Comment: the whole idea of using GridLayout is avoiding nested LinearLayouts, which are not good for performance (findViewById)

Answer (score 11):

Starting in **API 21** the notion of weight was added to **GridLayout**.

To support older android devices, you can use the **GridLayout from the v7 support library.**

```
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:22.2.1'
```

The following XML gives an example of how you can use weights to fill the screen width.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:id="@+id/choice_grid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:padding="4dp"

    grid:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
    grid:columnCount="2"
    grid:rowOrderPreserved="false"
    grid:useDefaultMargins="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
        grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#FF33B5E5"
        android:text="Tile1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
        grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#FF33B5E5"
        android:text="Tile2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
        grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#FF33B5E5"
        android:text="Tile3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
        grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#FF33B5E5"
        android:text="Tile4" />

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Comment: Dude, I was looking for `compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:22.2.1'` really long! Even reinstalled whole SDK thinking why it isn't resolved by building tools. Helped a lot!

Comment: preview is showing grid layout everything as supposed to be but when I run it cant see grid layout, what may be the problem?

Comment: Thanks for this example, although I am unable to achieve this programmatically, any ideas?

Comment: I have the same issue as @MirlanMaksitaliev

Comment: @MirlanMaksitaliev , follow my answer .

Comment: @adnan9011 forgot to write that the problem was solved that day. Just include please tag of grid layout <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout/> in your answer, beginners like me may confuse

Comment: @Carsten Are you using <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout/> as tag of grid layout?

Comment: Fast forward to 2020, `compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:22.2.1'` has changed to `implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'` and `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout` to `androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout`.

Answer (score 3):

If you use fragments you can prepare XML layout and than stratch critical elements programmatically

```
int thirdScreenWidth = (int)(screenWidth *0.33);

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, null);
View _container = view.findViewById(R.id.rim1container);
_container.getLayoutParams().width = thirdScreenWidth * 2;

_container = view.findViewById(R.id.rim2container);
_container.getLayoutParams().width = screenWidth - thirdScreenWidth * 2;

_container = view.findViewById(R.id.rim3container);
_container.getLayoutParams().width = screenWidth - thirdScreenWidth * 2;
```

This layout for 3 equal columns. First element takes 2x2
Result in the picture
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick follow up and note that it is possible now to use the support library with weighted spacing in GridLayout to achieve what you want, see:

> As of API 21, GridLayout's distribution of excess space accomodates the principle of weight. In the event that no weights are specified, the previous conventions are respected and columns and rows are taken as flexible if their views specify some form of alignment within their groups.
>   The flexibility of a view is therefore influenced by its alignment which is, in turn, typically defined by setting the gravity property of the child's layout parameters. If either a weight or alignment were defined along a given axis then the component is taken as flexible in that direction. If no weight or alignment was set, the component is instead assumed to be inflexible.

Answer (score 1):

I archive this using `LinearLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:height="166dp"
            android:text="Tile1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#6f19e5"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:text="Tile2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:height="126dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight=".50"
            android:background="#f1d600"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="Tile3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:height="126dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight=".50"
            android:background="#e75548"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:text="Tile4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:height="126dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight=".50"
            android:background="#29d217"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="Tile5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:height="126dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight=".50"
            android:background="#e519cb"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:height="176dp"
            android:text="Tile6"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#09eadd"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Here the modal]

Answer (score 1):

For other peeps: If you have to use GridLayout due to project requirements then use it but I would suggest trying out TableLayout as it seems much easier to work with and achieves a similar result.

Docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html

Example:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/test1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:text="Test 1"
            android:drawableTop="@mipmap/android_launcher"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/test2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:text="Test 2"
            android:drawableTop="@mipmap/android_launcher"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/test3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:text="Test 3"
            android:drawableTop="@mipmap/android_launcher"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/test4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:text="Test 4"
            android:drawableTop="@mipmap/android_launcher"
            />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/test5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:text="Test 5"
            android:drawableTop="@mipmap/android_launcher"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/test6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:text="Test 6"
            android:drawableTop="@mipmap/android_launcher"
            />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: Grid Layout]

```
       <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:rowCount="3"
        android:background="@drawable/background_down"
        android:layout_height="0dp">


        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:weightSum="3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/user" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Users"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:weightSum="3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/addusers" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Add Users"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:weightSum="3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/newspaper" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Report"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />
            </LinearLayout>



        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:weightSum="3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/settings" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Settings"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </GridLayout>
```

Full tutorials can be found here .

```
[Android Grid Layout With CardView and OnItemClickListener][2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Giving match_parent to inflated items will do the trick. GridLayout will automatically divide max parent length based on given column number and inflate those items fitting the whole screen.[image: give match_parent to the item]

Answer (score -1):

Do you know View.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener()

By this you can calculate the sizes.

I achieve your UI effect by GridView:

```
GridView g;
g.setNumColumns(2);
g.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_SPACING_UNIFORM);
```

Comment: The post was about GridLayout and not GridView. Maybe you have made a mistake reading.