# How to build my menu for android devices

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-size

I'm working on my game menu for android and I'm stuck to apply my layout for all devices screen size.

Do I have to size my layout in dp or with weight ?

I'am aware of doing many layout in layout-large, layout-small... and drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi ... but I'm still stuck.

How you will do it?

You can find a skeleton of what I want :
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/14/menuskeleton.jpg/

Thank you !

Comment: check out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10812552) and then with proper setPadding or setMargin between the childs can enable you to get the desired layout you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this [page](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) of google developers, has a description of how to develop for different screen sizes.

- http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

And this [page](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html) is the answer to your question about the size of your layout, it is between dp or weight.

- http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html

See [this](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html) also.

- http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to use the weight to keep interoperability with other formats tablet.

My solution :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#AAAAAA"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:ignore="DisableBaselineAlignment" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="NestedWeights" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#DDDDDD"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Shop"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#DDDDDD"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Ladder"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#DDDDDD"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Profil"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#DDDDDD"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Recap_All"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:ignore="DisableBaselineAlignment" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#DDDDDD"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="NestedWeights" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#DDDDDD"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="PLAY"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And result in picture :

[image]

I hope you have helped!

Comment: pot this as a comment. this is not an answer. its a suggestion

Comment: Thanks a lot, I modify my layout to implement some of your advice and it works really well ! Thanks again !