# Android GridView 1 full width item then 2 columns, how?

Tags: java, android, listview

I need the first item in my GridView to be twice the size of other items, then all next items to be same size which is half the first item size.

using GridView is not mandatory, it just seems to me it should be done using GridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the first item  out of the gridview in a RelativeLayout

[image]

it is not an elegant solution, but it's a solution

Comment: He, don't want that type of view as he written clearly. he want first should be full and next should be 1/2 and this should be upto to all dynamic record.

Comment: I think I`ll go this way, looks the easiest for me to accomplish

Answer (score 1):

You should go with GridLayout :-

here is a short tutorial http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/GridLayout-in-Android

custom arrangement in GridLayout :- [Heterogeneous GridLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812552/heterogeneous-gridlayout)

Comment: He, don't want that type of view as he written clearly. he want first should be full and next should be 1/2 and this should be upto to all dynamic record

Comment: StaggeredGridView doesnt seem to provide the thing I asked for. As for GridLayout, this is very generic, can you give specific steps or tutorial?

Comment: i have added a link .. please go through it

Comment: thanks, I`ll try it, so assuming I`ll get it done using gridlayout, I should wrap the grid layout inside a scrollView?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a linearlayout, set layout_width of all items to 0dp, set layout_weight of the first to 2 and layout_weight of the others to 1