# Android Images display in Tiles

Tags: android, imageview, tiles

I want to display images into tiles like windows phone menu. We can do this using AsymmetricGridView library. But I want to display in single imageview not in GridView. Do like this into Single Imageview,
[image]

Is it Possible to do like this into single view or imageview? if it is then suggest me how?

Comment: Don't you want to get different click event on different element ..??

Comment: no, just display like tiles in single view. nothing at all.

Comment: Then i think you have to create dynamic image.. You can use third party libraries that does create photo grid..!!

Comment: if you about that please suggest me any library...

Comment: Without using 3rd party libraries (which I'm allergic to): use the GridLayout  container: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812552/heterogeneous-gridlayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

refer this , it might help you
https://github.com/jacobmoncur/QuiltViewLibrary

Comment: if i dont want to scroll it and only fix six, it can be possible??

Comment: i guess by removing "app:scrollOrientation="horizontal|vertical" , might be possible, but i am not sure, you can give a try

Answer (score 2):

for this purpose you can use `AsymmetricGridView`.
An Android custom ListView that implements multiple columns and variable sized elements.Please note that this is currently in a preview state. This basically means that the API is not fixed and you should expect changes between releases.
firstly Add lib from here:https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView.
and then Add this in layout file:

```
<com.felipecsl.asymmetricgridview.library.widget.AsymmetricGridView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/listView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

and In your activity class:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (AsymmetricGridView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    // Choose your own preferred column width
    listView.setRequestedColumnWidth(Utils.dpToPx(this, 120));
    final List<AsymmetricItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

    // initialize your items array
adapter = new ListAdapter(this, listView, items);
AsymmetricGridViewAdapter asymmetricAdapter =
        new AsymmetricGridViewAdapter<>(this, listView, adapter);
    listView.setAdapter(asymmetricAdapter);
}
```

Toggle to enable/disable reordering of elements to better fill the grid:

```
 // Setting to true will move items up and down to better use the space
// Defaults to false.
listView.setAllowReordering(true);
listView.isAllowReordering(); // true
```

enjoy your code:)

Comment: you you need to break an image into tiles?

Answer (score -1):

You can use StaggeredGrid or PinterestListView. Please visit below links:

https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid

https://github.com/GDG-Korea/PinterestLikeAdapterView

https://github.com/vladexologija/PinterestListView

Comment: ya i know using this it can be possible. but i want to do it into single view.