# Dynamic Android Grid Layout with custom positioning and sizing of children

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview, grid-layout, android-gridlayout

I'm currently trying to create an Android grid layout from custom elements(taken from a db) and am in need of suggestions on how to implement it. The grid should have 6 columns and it should be scroll vertically. Each Grid Element(Item) has columnSpan, columnRow, xPosition and yPosition.

Here is an example of the desired result:
[image]

I tried with a GridLayout, but there is no adapter support with it.
I tried with Grid View, but can't manage to make it look right.
I need a robust solution, but at this point I'm desperate just for a working solution.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812552/heterogeneous-gridlayout) is an old post with hacky over-complicated solutions. Has something changed? Is there a good solution to this problem? And why does this problem exist in the first place?

Comment: didi you found any solution for this