# Android GridLayout confusion

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to use a GridLayout with 2 rows and "4" columns to achieve the below:

[image: Desired GridLayout]

Since I figured that I can't make row 2's column 1 span 1½ column, I figured that if I instead used say 8 columns, I could just span each column in row 1 over 2 columns, and then for row 2 column 1 I could span that over 3 columns

However if I try this I get the following result:

[image: GridLayout as i can get it]

**How can i get the result of the first one using GridLayout?**

---

**EDIT** 
Doesn't have to be GridLayout, if theres an obvious alternative

Comment: Hi! You might find this link helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812552/heterogeneous-gridlayout

Comment: Please add your XML