# how in GridLayout (Android) to fit the last two blocks to full width?

Tags: android-studio

I am currently learning the Android front-end development, and our teacher gave us this task:

We need to create the next grid in Android Studio: [Task Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mM2BX.png) using `GridLayout`. For now I only created [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnFgs.png).

Is there way to display the last two blocks of the `GridLayout` in full width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [SpanSizeLookup](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup).

Something like:

```
val layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity, 2)
layoutManager.spanSizeLookup = object : GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    override fun getSpanSize(position: Int): Int {
        return when (position) {
            YOUR_CONDITION -> 2
            else -> 1
        }
   }
}
recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
```

Replace YOUR_CONDITION with some logic fits your requirements to make a cell twice higher.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it works, but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10928623) does not recommend it.

You could just put a `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="vertical"` and `android:width="match_parent"` or another `GridLayout` below your `GridLayout`.

If you don't have any wrapping layout, wrap both of them into a `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="vertical"` and put all the properties of your original `GridLayout` there.