# Auto-scaling images in a grid

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have a 3x3 GridLayout of images that I want to auto-scale to fill their parent. No matter what I try, what I put for scaling or width, the images stay the same size. The container changes size, but the underlying image doesn't scale. What am I doing wrong? I know that not all the images below have the same settings - I was just playing with different things at once to see what they'd do.

```
<GridLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:rowCount="3"
    android:columnCount="3">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/icon2"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/sample"
        android:background="#AAAAAA"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/icon3"
        android:src="@drawable/sample"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/icon4"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/sample"
        android:background="#AAAAAA"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="2" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/icon5"
        android:src="@drawable/sample"
        android:background="#AAAAAA"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:width="100dp"
        android:height="100dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/icon6"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/sample"
        android:background="#AAAAAA"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/icon7"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/sample"
        android:background="#AAAAAA"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="2" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/icon8"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/sample"
        android:background="#AAAAAA"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="0" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/icon9"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/sample"
        android:background="#AAAAAA"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="1" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/icon1"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/sample"
        android:background="#AAAAAA"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="2" />
</GridLayout>
```

I want the result to look something like the grid in this image. I'm less concerned about the text for now, but if you have any bright ideas on that, feel free to add them :)

[image: Desired result]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can achieve auto scaling in GridLayout using XMl.
we can fix it pro-grammatically by calculating the Screen size and width.
Read this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347846/how-to-use-the-gridlayout-to-fit-screen-size) . Hope it will help you.