# How to get row and column position/number of a view in GridLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-gridlayout

I am developing an app for in which i am using Grid Layout to arrange TextViews.
TextViews are added dynamically.

now what i want is when user clicks on any click listener , a toast should be popped up giving position of textview in terms of row and column number. ( i am also using column spanning).

till now i have implemented click listener on textView but i am not able to figure out how i can get its position to show in toast.

Grid Layout is added in a Horizontal ScrollView which in turn is added into a Scroll View , i need this setup to get scrolling in both direction.

my layout XML :-

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/vertical_scroll_view3">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_scroll_view3">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical"

            />
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

i am following following question to add view dynamically

[How to make a GridLayout fit screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347846/how-to-use-the-gridlayout-to-fit-screen-size)

my gridlayout is :-
[image]

and its Grid Layout not Grid View !!

Any suggestion is appreciated !!

Comment: Where is Grid's Layout's xml code ???

Comment: i am adding textView dynamically to it