# Android GridLayout: How do I set the size of a component?

Tags: android, android-layout

I just found Android has `GridLayout` and I wrote this little demo:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="2" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="Button 1" />    

</GridLayout>
```

Since I set both `rowCount` and `columnCount` to 2, and both `rowSpan` and `columnSpan` to 1, I expected something like this:

[image]

However, this is what I actually got:

[image]

Does anyone know how should I fix this problem? Or do I use `GridLayout` in the wrong way? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gridlayout does not support weight. To place equal amounts of space around a component in a cell group; use CENTER alignment (or gravity).
You can try setting the width/length of your components pragmatically. For reference look at this question
[How to make a GridLayout fit screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347846/how-to-use-the-gridlayout-to-fit-screen-size)