# Don't understand how to use GridLayout.spec()

Tags: java, android, grid-layout, specifications

This GridLayout is going in my app that has a lot of levels.  Each level has a different number of rows and columns.  I assume that this GridLayout would be my best bet to use to satisfy my needs.  Also, all need to be done at runtime prorammatically.

I am having trouble understanding how to use `GridLayout.spec()`.  I am trying to follow [this excellent example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347846/how-to-use-the-gridlayout-to-fit-screen-size) but just cannot grasp it fully.  Let's say, for example, I want a GridLayout with 3 columns and 4 rows.

```
GridLayout.LayoutParms params1 = new GridLayout.Layout(rowSpec, columnSpec);  //what's parameters?

gameplayGridLayout.setColumnCount(3);
gameplayGridLayout.setRowCount(4);

puzzle.addView(gameplayGridLayout, params1);
```

In my linked example above, he used code like below to set the `"specs"`.

```
Spec row1 = GridLayout.spec(0, 2);
Spec row2 = GridLayout.spec(2);
Spec row3 = GridLayout.spec(3);
Spec row4 = GridLayout.spec(4, 2);

Spec col0 = GridLayout.spec(0);
Spec col1 = GridLayout.spec(1); 
Spec colspan2 = GridLayout.spec(0, 2);
```

I don't understand the parameters of those variables either.  I've tried reading the documentation but it didn't give me any clarity.  Can someone help me with my example code of the 3x4 GridLayout which also helps explain what the `Spec`s are?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I didn't exactly understand your question, but here are some examples that explain the syntax:

```
Spec row1 = GridLayout.spec(0, 2); //here you set row to be first row and it takes 2 cells in height.

Spec row2  = GridLayout.spec(2); //this row goes under row1 and it takes 1 cell(default size = 1)
```

and etc.

```
Spec col0 = GridLayout.spec(0); //same here - first column, width = 1 cell.

Spec colspan2 = GridLayout.spec(0, 2);
```

so you can do like this:

```
Spec row1 = GridLayout.spec(0);
Spec row2 = GridLayout.spec(1);
Spec row3 = GridLayout.spec(2);
Spec row4 = GridLayout.spec(3);

Spec col0 = GridLayout.spec(0);
Spec col1 = GridLayout.spec(1); 
Spec col2 = GridLayout.spec(2);

GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(this);
GridLayout.LayoutParams first = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row1, col0);
/*Here you can set options for first cell which is in first row and first column.*/
first.width = screenWidth;
first.height = quarterScreenWidth * 2;
twoByTwo1.setLayoutParams(first);
twoByTwo1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
twoByTwo1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
twoByTwo1.setText("TOP");
twoByTwo1.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
gridLayout.addView(twoByTwo1, first)
//You can set all cells like above.
```

I hope this helps. :)