# How to use GridLayout.Spec for a column extending multiple rows?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

I'm trying to dynamically create a table with 2 rows and 4 columns. But the size of rows and columns in each case should not be the same. Perhaps I will attach a picture:

I would like:

[image]

As I understand, when i don't use XML markup to achieve this using a GridLayout.Spec in  setLayoutParams

But I don't understand what parameters I need to pass in GridLayout.Spec ?

If I want to merge the first column in the first row with the first column of the second row, what should I specify in

```
GridLayout.LayoutParams (GridLayout.Spec rowSpec, GridLayout.Spec columnSpec)
```

?

and what is Spec ?

I saw the examples [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871690/dont-understand-how-to-use-gridlayout-spec) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347846/how-to-make-a-gridlayout-fit-screen-size) but do not fully understand how it works.

If in the case of XML markup I can use layout_rowSpan and layout_columnSpan to merge rows or columns then how to do it in dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take look at this code below to get the layout that you're looking for. Comments are added to explain the values used in the `GridLayout.Spec` creation.

```
// simple grid layout with WRAP_CONTENT width and height
GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.grid_layout);

// face view takes 2 rows, 1 column -- zero index based
GridLayout.Spec faceRow = GridLayout.spec(0, 2); // starts row 0, takes 2 rows
GridLayout.Spec faceCol = GridLayout.spec(0); // starts col 0, takes 1 col

GridLayout.Spec titleRow = GridLayout.spec(0); // starts row 0, takes 1 row
GridLayout.Spec titleCol = GridLayout.spec(1, 3); // starts col 1, takes 3 cols

GridLayout.Spec plusRow = GridLayout.spec(1); // starts row 1, takes 1 row
GridLayout.Spec plusCol = GridLayout.spec(1); // starts col 1, takes 1 col

GridLayout.Spec minusRow = GridLayout.spec(1); // starts row 1, takes 1 row
GridLayout.Spec minusCol = GridLayout.spec(2); // starts col 1, takes 1 col

GridLayout.Spec checkRow = GridLayout.spec(1); // starts row 1, takes 1 row
GridLayout.Spec checkCol = GridLayout.spec(3); // starts col 1, takes 1 col

// create the LayoutParams using our row/col for each view
GridLayout.LayoutParams faceParams = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(faceRow, faceCol);
faceParams.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_VERTICAL); // fill vertical so we take up the full 2 rows
// dummy text views to fill some space
TextView faceText = new TextView(this);
faceText.setPadding(32, 32, 32, 32); // add some random padding to make the views bigger
faceText.setLayoutParams(faceParams);
faceText.setText("FACE");
faceText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
faceText.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
gridLayout.addView(faceText, faceParams);

GridLayout.LayoutParams titleParams = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(titleRow, titleCol);
titleParams.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL); // fill horizontal so we take up the full 3 columns
TextView titleText = new TextView(this);
titleText.setPadding(32, 32, 32, 32);
titleText.setLayoutParams(titleParams);
titleText.setText("TITLE");
titleText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
titleText.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
gridLayout.addView(titleText, titleParams);

GridLayout.LayoutParams minusParams = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(minusRow, minusCol);
TextView minusText = new TextView(this);
minusText.setPadding(32, 32, 32, 32);
minusText.setLayoutParams(minusParams);
minusText.setText("MIN");
minusText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
minusText.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
gridLayout.addView(minusText, minusParams);

GridLayout.LayoutParams plusParams = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(plusRow, plusCol);
TextView plusText = new TextView(this);
plusText.setPadding(32, 32, 32, 32);
plusText.setLayoutParams(plusParams);
plusText.setText("PLS");
plusText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
plusText.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
gridLayout.addView(plusText, plusParams);

GridLayout.LayoutParams checkParams = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(checkRow, checkCol);
TextView checkText = new TextView(this);
checkText.setPadding(32, 32, 32, 32);
checkText.setLayoutParams(faceParams);
checkText.setText("CHK");
checkText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
checkText.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
gridLayout.addView(checkText, checkParams);
```

Hope this helps with the understanding of the `GridLayout.Spec`.

Comment: I will pray to God that you had gone to work in Google and you write the developer guide . Now I understand how it works ! Thank you.

Comment: No problem! If it answers your question, please be sure to mark it as the accepted answer :)