# TextView add to GridLayout dynamically

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I have a problem, that i dont know how can i add a textview to a gridlayout.
I have an xml:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:text="TextView" />
```

And would like to do this xml code dynamically. How can i do this? I know how to create textview, but i dont know how to add to the gridlayout...

Comment: Use `addView(...)`. Also [this](https://www.google.at/search?q=add+a+view+programmatically+android).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
GridLayout gv = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridlayout);
TextView tv = new TextView(context);
tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.TOP);
tv.setText("TextView");
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(Set your column and row information as params);
tv.setLayoutParams(params);
gv.addView(tv);
```

You can't paste the code in and it will need to be tested and changed to fit (it won't just work). But it should give you the general idea.

Comment: So i think i dont understand what is the gridview and what is the gridlayout..
and how to set column and row info as params? this is what i dont know

Comment: Oh I misread the post, you can change GridView to GridLayout, I have updated my post.

Comment: and how to set column and row info as params? this is what i dont know

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347846/how-to-use-the-gridlayout-to-fit-screen-size

Comment: Can you give an example of "Set your column and row information as params"?