# Android - Addind Cells Dyncamically in a GridLayout

Tags: android, android-custom-view, grid-layout, android-inflate, android-gridlayout

I'm working on a Calendar and I am using a GridLayout for it, now I want to add events. My event is a cell in a specific position (row, column) and maybe the event it would take 2 rows (events longer than 1 hour). I did an example in xml, but I don't know how to add my events dynamically.

My XML:

```
<GridLayout
                    android:id="@+id/gridBodyCalendar"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:columnCount="8"
                    android:rowCount="24"
                        android:background="@color/blanco">
                    <!-- Cells without Events-->                            
                        .
                        .
                        .

                    <LinearLayout
                        style="@style/WeeklyHourCell"
                        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                        android:layout_column="4"
                        android:layout_row="4">
                        <Space
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    <!-- After I create all cells, for ui testing I added my event cells in a specific row/columns; it seems to replace or overlap the previous cell of the x,y position -->
                    <!-- Wednesday from 16:00 to 17:30-->
                    <!-- RowSpan 2 because it takes longer than 1 hour -->
                    <LinearLayout
                        style="@style/WeeklyHourCell"
                        android:layout_row="16"
                        android:layout_column="3"
                        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        >
                        <!-- Space; is the event doesn't start exactly at 16:00 it would need a weight != from 0-->
                        <Space
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0" />
                        <!-- The event with styles and specific properties -->
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/linReunionInternaEjemplo"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:background="@color/fondo_reunion_interna_calendario"
                            android:layout_weight="0.75"
                            >
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="5dp"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:background="@color/color_reunion_interna_calendario"
                                ></LinearLayout>
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                                android:orientation="vertical">
                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                    android:text="Jhon Smith"
                                    android:textColor="@color/color_reunion_interna_calendario"
                                    android:maxLines="1"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                    android:textColor="@color/color_reunion_interna_calendario"
                                    android:maxLines="1"
                                    android:text="San Borja"/>
                            </LinearLayout>

                        </LinearLayout>
                        <!-- End Event -->
                        <!-- Space for the event that doesn't finish exactly at 18:00-->
                        <Space
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.25"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    .
                    .
                    .
        </GridLayout>
```

The xml draw a event like I wish, but I need to load multiple events from my database so I can't create my events in my xml. I need to create my events programatically, set its properties and add it in a specific row/column. How can I start to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TextView add to GridLayout dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695210/textview-add-to-gridlayout-dynamically)

Comment: Yes, those are textviews, but the concept of the `addView` method is what you need