# Add custom attributes of layout to children

Tags: android

I have layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/grid_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/default_grid_height"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <!--I need add to this child attribute "app:layout_*"-->
    <Button
        android:text="1"
        app:layout_columnSpan="2"
        app:layout_columnWeight="2"
        app:layout_rowWeight="3"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

I need to **programmatically** add child to this layout container `(support.v7.widget.GridLayout)` with custom attributes supported by this layout. How i can do this? 
Assume I can do something like that, but not found something method like tihs.

```
widget = CustomWidget(context)
widget.addParam("app:layout_rowWeight", 3) // how??
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't difficult to add something to `GridLayout` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695210/textview-add-to-gridlayout-dynamically). But you need to know what do you want to add.

```
GridLayout gv = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.grid_layout);
TextView tv = new TextView(context);
tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.TOP);
tv.setText("TextView");
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(Set your column and row information as params);
tv.setLayoutParams(params);
gv.addView(tv);
```

Comment: Okay, i know how add child views to some ViewGroup. How i can set *custom layout params* to child of this ViewGroup? In my case param = "app:layout_columnSpan = 3", and ViewGroup = GridLayout from support library

Comment: `param.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(A); param.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(B);`

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is, we can make it very simple, Just create one method in your custom class for that,

If you are setting in XML you can call like this `app:layout_rowWeight` so that you can get in your Custom class in TypedArray.

But for Jave, you can create a separate method and you can achieve same.

Ex Check [TextView](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java) Android source code, and search `setTextColor` method.