# android xml GridLayout won't auto-fill fields/compile

Tags: android, android-layout

android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout does not work for me. I tried using it as the outer layout and as an inner layout. Fields like app:columnCount do not work and throw errors at compile time. They do not auto fill despite me having the correct xmlns fields. My IDE is Android Studio Canary and you can see my gradle below:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.support.android.designlibdemo"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"


compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3.4'
```

I want to try GridLayout to facilitate consistent padding and margins. In the end, all I want is the easiest solution. [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22084723/2355058) link shows nested linear layouts with weights. I want to overcome this terrible design for something much more elegant. If you prefer it or something else to GRID, I would love to know.

Comment: What compile time errors are you getting? Exactly what Canary version of Studio are you using?

Comment: Solved http://stackoverflow.com/a/21100896/2355058

Comment: The solution involves deleting the .idea folder and .lml files

http://stackoverflow.com/a/21100896/2355058