# Destroy the space of one button to another button in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I met some trouble when I designed the layout of the calculator. As the pic shows, I want it to look like the pic1 but no matter how I change the code, it still looks like pic2. Here is the pics and my code! Hope someone can help me solve this problem.

(pic1)
[image]

(pic2)
[image]

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question_text_view"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:padding="24dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:orientation = "horizontal" 
        android:layout_weight="0">

        <Button
            android:id = "@+id/C_button"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"

            android:text = "C" />

        <Button
            android:id = "@+id/del_button"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:text = "del" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/divide_button"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:text="/"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mul_button"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"      
            android:text="X"/>
    </LinearLayout>    

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:orientation = "horizontal" 
        android:layout_weight="0">

        <Button
            android:id = "@+id/seven"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:text = "7" />

        <Button
            android:id = "@+id/eight_button"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:text = "8" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nine_button"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:text="9"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/minus_button"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"      
            android:text="-"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:orientation = "horizontal" 
        android:layout_weight="0">

        <Button
            android:id = "@+id/four"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:text = "4" />

        <Button
            android:id = "@+id/five_button"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:text = "5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/six_button"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:text="6"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/plus_button"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"      
            android:text="+"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:orientation = "horizontal" 
        android:layout_weight="0">

        <Button
            android:id = "@+id/one"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:text = "1" />

        <Button
            android:id = "@+id/two_button"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:text = "2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/three_button"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:text="3"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/equal_button"
            android:layout_rowSpan="2"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:text="="/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: **1** - There's some padding in your styles or themes. Remove it. **2** - You don't need to nest layouts (it's bad for performances). A GridLayout is better suited for this UI.

Comment: @Ken Choi what you are doing is adding buttons and what there in PIC-1 is not button as pointed by Frank it is a grid view that's why you are not getting that look

Comment: @dex okay, thanks! i know what's my problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use grid layout for this

visit http://sampleprogramz.com/android/gridlayout.php

this would help you - [How to make a GridLayout fit screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347846/how-to-use-the-gridlayout-to-fit-screen-size)

Answer (score 2):

Just replace the background of your `Button`, Android's default Button has transparent pixels in background image