# Assigning custom buttons dynamically into a custom grid layout

Tags: android, android-layout, grid-layout

I have a requirement to display a question along with a list of options that i am getting from server. Each option has a title and an image and these options should be clickable. So I am creating a class ImageButton extending to RelativeLayout and each option is an ImageButton. I am also creating a class ImageButtonGroup extending to GridLayout and dynamimcally adding all the ImageButtons to this ImageButtonGroup.

It works fine except for the alignment of the ImageButtons. The ImageButton's size depends on the length of the title text (the image is of same size for all options) and I am having hard time in distributing equal cell space to each ImageButton in the grid layout. See below my code where I am adding ImageButtons to ImageButtonGroup:

```
ImageButtonGroup imageButtonGroup =
          (ImageButtonGroup)
              mInflater.inflate(
                  R.layout.button_image_response_layout, holder.richTextContainer, false);
      int total = item.getMessage().getResponseOptions().size();
      int col = 3;
      int row = total / col;
      imageButtonGroup.setColumnCount(col);
      imageButtonGroup.setRowCount(row + 1);
      for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        ResponseOption responseOption = item.getMessage().getResponseOptions().get(i);
        ImageButtonView imageButtonView =
            (ImageButtonView)
                mInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.image_button_layout, holder.richTextContainer, false);
        imageButtonView.setData(
            responseOption.getImage(), responseOption.getViewText(), responseOption.getValue());
        GridLayout.LayoutParams gridParam = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
        gridParam.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        gridParam.topMargin = 10;
        gridParam.bottomMargin = 10;
        gridParam.width = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        gridParam.height = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        imageButtonGroup.addView(imageButtonView, gridParam);
```

This gets me the following view:(The text isn't always Happy as shown below)
[image]

How to dynamically allocate fixed sized cell to these buttons inside a grid layout?

Comment: Can you put a screen of the actual behaviour of your gridview?

Comment: Updated the actual screens.

Answer (score 0):

You can to specify row and column while creating the GridLayoutParams so that it will handle itself the matching of the size dependending on the total space:

```
GridLayout.LayoutParams first = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row, col);
```

> GridLayout.LayoutParams(GridLayout.Spec rowSpec, GridLayout.Spec
>   columnSpec)
>
> Constructs a new LayoutParams instance for this rowSpec and
>   columnSpec.

In your specific case it will be something like :

```
    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            ResponseOption responseOption = item.getMessage().getResponseOptions().get(i);
            ImageButtonView imageButtonView =
                (ImageButtonView)
                    mInflater.inflate(
                        R.layout.image_button_layout, holder.richTextContainer, false);
            imageButtonView.setData(
                responseOption.getImage(), responseOption.getViewText(), responseOption.getValue());
Spec row = GridLayout.spec(Math.round(i / 3);
Spec col = GridLayout.spec(i % 3);
            GridLayout.LayoutParams gridParam = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row, col);
            gridParam.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            gridParam.topMargin = 10;
            gridParam.bottomMargin = 10;
            gridParam.width = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            gridParam.height = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            imageButtonGroup.addView(imageButtonView, gridParam);
```

Comment: GridLayout.LayoutParams gridParam = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(Math.round(i / 3), i % 3); gives "Cannot resolve constructor LayoutParams(int, int)"

Comment: Yup i made a mistake . You need to use Spec object to pass to the constructor. Check the edited answer.

Comment: This had no effect . I'm thinking if weight can somehow come to my rescue. But i am not sure.

Comment: Maybe. I think this topic may help your case : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347846/how-to-make-a-gridlayout-fit-screen-size

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this taking a hint from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347846/how-to-make-a-gridlayout-fit-screen-size)

I got the screen width, calculated my layout size in terms of %age point (came out to be 70% of the total width) and divided it by 3 (the number of column). So basically what i did is:

```
int dWidth = (int)(presenter.getView().getScreenWidth() * .70) / 3;
gridParam.width = dWidth;
```